# Open Command Prompt with specific directory using Python

Tags: python, directory, admin, command-prompt

How can I open command prompt with specific directory using Python?

I could just run command prompt using Python but I'm unable to open with specific directory.

```
import os
os.system("start cmd")
```

Comment: `cmd` can take arguments (run `cmd /?` to see them) you can do `cmd /K cd c:/` to start cmd at `c:`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can open the specific path using this

```
import os
os.system("start cmd /K cd C:\\Users\\Name\\Desktop\\File" )
```

Comment: Great thanks a lot. Now I have to execute the below command using python. Could you please help with the flow                                                                                                 
py <filename> –V <variant string> -p <path to the flash files>

Comment: @SujiRyali What exactly are you trying to achieve? Are you trying to get the version of python?

Comment: no I have to flash the component. For which I am opening command prompt with specific directory using python. and then execute flashing command next an extension to opening CMD          
         py <filename> –V <variant string> -p <path>

Comment: @SujiRyali You can change your working directory to the desired path and then input the call. I have answered your other question.

Comment: If I would like to open the command prompt in the directory where I run the python script that opens the command prompt is. How could I write the syntax after `cd...`?

Comment: This only works so long as you are starting within drive C: